# How to get conditional formatting by vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, format

Good afternoon,

I currently have this table.

Sub table()

```
Range("A2:D2").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Name"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Birthday"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Years old"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Presentation date"
Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Mary"
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5/2/2004"
Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "17"
Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2/9/2022"
Range("D4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12/16/2022"
Range("D5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8/15/2022"
Range("D6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6/5/2022"
Range("D7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1/5/2022"
Range("D8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6/5/2022"
Range("D9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12/6/2022"
Range("D10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12/19/2022"
Range("D11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2/14/2022"
Range("C6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "39"
Range("C7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "26"
Range("C9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "20"
Range("C10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "48"
Range("C11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "76"
Range("A6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "John"
Range("B6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4/3/1982"
Range("B7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12/7/1995"
Range("B9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5/1/2001"
Range("B10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "11/15/1973"
Range("B11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10/19/1945"
Range("A11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Bia"
Range("A10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Greny"
Range("A9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Amy"
Range("A7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Louis"
Range("A5:D5,A6:D6,A8:D8,A9:D9,A10:D10,A11:D11").Select
Range("A11").Activate
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
```

End Sub

Does anyone know the code to conditionally format the rows (paint the table cells horizontally), based on the age of the individuals?

Where:

Sub conditions()

```
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "<18"
Range("G2").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "grey"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "<18"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "<=18"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "grey"
Range("F3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "19-25"
Range("G3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yellow"
Range("F4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "26-40"
Range("G4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "dark yellow"
Range("F5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "41-60"
Range("G5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "orange"
Range("F6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ">=61"
Range("G6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "green"
Range("H4").Select
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("F2:G6").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = False
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Range("H11").Select
```

End Sub

And at the same time sort the presentation date in ascending order (but getting grouped by names, that is, sorted by groups)?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try the macro recorder while adding a conditional formatting rule?

Comment: @PEH, for 5 conditions, I don't know the code. Perhaps, if I only needed 3 conditions I had used the excel menu. Can you help me?

Comment: You can use the Excel menu for 5 conditions too

Answer (score 2):

Just add 5 different rules to the desired range

```
With Range("A:A")
    ' <= 18
    .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLessEqual, Formula1:="=18").Interior.Color = 10000
    
    ' 19 … 25
    .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=19", Formula2:="=25").Interior.Color = 20000
    
    ' 26 … 40
    .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=26", Formula2:="=40").Interior.Color = 65535
    
    ' 41 … 59
    .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=41", Formula2:="=59").Interior.Color = 49407

    ' >= 60
    .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=60").Interior.Color = 13311
End With
```